# Condition check using XPath Query

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

Suppose you have a XML structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<ISExport Version="2.4" productVersion="2.4">
<ControlFlow name="CF_Order" typeId="2" >
<Variables>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_FromTS" datatype="TIMESTAMP" >
   </Element>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_ToTS" datatype="TIMESTAMP" >
   </Element>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_TableName" datatype="VARCHAR"     size="128" >
   </Element>
</Variables>
</ControlFlow>
<ControlFlow name="CF_Action" typeId="2" >
<Variables>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_FromTS" datatype="TIMESTAMP" >
   </Element>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_ToTS" datatype="TIMESTAMP" >
   </Element>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_TableName" datatype="VARCHAR"      size="128" >
   </Element>
</Variables>
</ControlFlow>
<ControlFlow name="CF_Task" typeId="2" >
<Variables>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_FromTS" datatype="TIMESTAMP" >
   </Element>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_ToTS" datatype="TIMESTAMP" >
   </Element>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_TableName" datatype="VARCHAR"        size="255" >
   </Element>
</Variables>
</ControlFlow>
<ControlFlow name="CF_Sales" typeId="2" >
<Variables>
   <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_FromTS" datatype="TIMESTAMP" >
  </Element>
  <Element paramType="LOCAL" name="$V_ToTS" datatype="TIMESTAMP" >
  </Element>
</Variables>
</ControlFlow>
</ISExport>
```

How would I write XPATH queries to

- List all ControlFlow names where the Element `name = $V_TableName` and Element `size <> '128'`
- List all ControlFlow names which do not have Element `name = $V_TableName`

I am using the XPATH plugin of Notepad++. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried with outputs

Comment: I tried something like this //ControlFlow/Variables/Element[contains(@name,'$V_TableName')] This lists me the Element Node with name and size attribute, which wasn't really helpful. I am new to XPATH and so finding it little difficult.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update for #1, to make sure we are testing the attributes of the same element -

```
//ControlFlow[Variables/Element[@name='$V_TableName' and not(@size = '128')]]/@name
```

Try these

1)List all ControlFlow names where the Element name = $V_TableName and Element size <> '128'

```
//ControlFlow[Variables/Element/@name='$V_TableName' and Variables/Element/@size != '128']/@name
```

2) List all ControlFlow names which do not have Element name = $V_TableName

```
//ControlFlow[not(Variables/Element/@name='$V_TableName')]/@name
```

Comment: `Variables/Element/@size != '128'` returns true if at least one node in the node-set has a value that is not equal to 128. You perhaps intended `not(Variables/Element/@size = '128')` which is true if none of the nodes is equal to 128. In fact, I don't think answer (1) does what it says because the two conditions can be true for different Element nodes.

Comment: Upvote for Michael Kay's comment. Answer updated for checking attributes of the same Element.